Computational framing of topological counterexamples
Bit of a soft question here, but bear with me:
Topology is infamous as a source of weird counterexamples.  Pretty much anyone who has been through a traditional introductory topology course can recall a number of "pathological spaces" that demonstrate odd behavior of the "bare" definition, resolved by the addition of additional axioms (e.g. separability).
The motivation/context for these counterexamples is usually abstract, and framed in terms of the topological formalisms themselves.  The "pathological" behavior of these counterexamples is typically represented as a logical contradiction in the formal proof process, augmented where necessary by spatial intuition.
There's nothing wrong with this, but the engineer in me finds it unsatisfying - as if the problem has been left half-complete.  Weird counterexamples in topology are interesting in their own right, but I can't say that I really understand how most (or even that many) of them relate to actual problems in application.  And, to me, that's what feels like complete understanding - not just when I can reliably identify the point of symbolic proof failure, but when I can tie it to a pathological behavior of a computation that I actually want to do about something in reality.
Are there any sources that treat topological counterexamples in this way?  I know there are ways to tie topology systematically to more "concrete" or "application-adjacent" fields of mathematics (e.g. graph theory).  Is there a systematic way of understanding what, for example, different separability axioms mean in terms of the behavior-in-the-limit of concrete calculations or algorithms on triangulations of spaces?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
